# PHP, Composer, PHP dependency manager

Tags: php, composer-php

I am starting a new PHP project, and I wanted to pull some php components such as "nesbot/carbon" using **composer**. But when I create a **composer.json** file and try to run composer install command, it downloads other files from my previous projects that I don's want.

Even when I try to *run "composer install" with out having a composer.json file in an empty folder*, it downloads some previous dependencies from caches. I didn't get that from where it's reading composer.json. Am stuck in the middle of project.

How can I create a fresh project with composer?

Comment: You could perhaps start by showing us your composer.json file

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "1.21.0"
    }
}

Comment: Might sound silly, but are you sure you're running `composer install` from the folder you got anything inside? Maybe on the terminal you're located in a different folder with a `package.json` file.
Could you show us what is it returned if you run `ls -l` from your terminal?

Answer (score 0):

To create a fresh project with `composer`, run

```
$ composer init
```

in the root directory of that project.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#init.